# sql combining 2 queries with different order by group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I am counting the most frequent response in a database and ranking them by highest amount so using group by and order by.

The following shows how to do it for one:

```
select health, count(health) as count 
from [Health].[Questionaire] 
group by Health 
order by count(Health) desc
```

which outputs the following:

```
Health       Count
-----------  -----
Very Good    6
Good         5
Poor         4
```

I would like to do with another column on the same table another query similar to the following so two queries using one sql statement like the following:

```
Health       Count    Diet       Count
-----------  -----   -----       -----
Very Good    6        Very Good   6
Good         5        Good        4
Poor         4        Poor        3
```

UPDATE!!

Hello this is how the table looks like at the moment

```
ID           Diet              Health      
-----------  -----             -------       
101          Very Good         Very Good   
102          Poor              Good        
103          Poor              Poor
```

I would like to do with another column on the same table another query similar to the following so two queries using one sql statement like the following:

```
Health       Count    Diet       Count
-----------  -----   -----       -----
Very Good    2        Very Good   1
Poor         1        Good        1
Good         0        Poor        1
```

Can anyone please help me out with this one? 
Can provide further clarification if needed!

Comment: Can you put an example with different values? Like for Diet count you have say VG 1 G 5 and P 7 ? And arrange the values like you spect?

Comment: Essentially this is a survey where people answer questions so when I have count it is the amount of people that say that their diet is  very good, good or poor so most people (6 people) say that their diet is good

Comment: I'm asking this because depending on the values the order of the values will be entiry different from one column to another given the order by mecanism. It order by columns order, so if you tell it to order first count column no matter what it is on the second it will order that one first. And if you tell it to order by the two count columns it will order by the first one considering the second which can messy your order.

Comment: sorry i'm half understanding what you are saying are you essentially saying that it is not possible to use count twice? or very difficult to

Comment: how many tables do you have data from ? is Diet OptionB ? Seems you have neglected to normalize your data. You have not included enough information to solve the question

Comment: To solve this problem correctly we need some more information about the tables. For example, where do you get your diet information from?

Comment: Essentially there is a table called Questionaire were all the columns id, health and diet are stored containing information of either good, very good and poor

Comment: Is this all you need ? select Health, count(OptionA) CountHealth, Count(OptionB) CountDiet
from [Health].[Questionaire] 
group by health

Comment: Please edit your question with table schema and sample data only way to fix your problem

Comment: @t-clausen.dk the issue with that query is that it does not count the results collectively for example the very good count is broken to 2, 3 , 1, 1 rather than outputing the count as 6 (I hope that makes sense)

Comment: @user2520014 well if the value of OptionA/OptionB is null it isnt counted. Which values can it have ? Maybe you could change the question to include data and table description

Comment: It is possible, but it may not be ordered as you want. Thats is what I'm trying to say. It depends on what you want.

Comment: What is in column `optionA`? Why is it even necessary? Don't you just need 3 columns `id, health, diet`? Also, your example output has 2 less in the diet grand total (6+4+3) than the health grand total (6+5+4), but shouldn't the grand totals for health and diet be equal, because every row has 1 health value and 1 diet value?

Comment: I have updated the question hopefully gives a clearer picture and sorry it should have said health not option A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 different ways of doing it, notice i removed the redundant column:

Test data:

```
DECLARE @t table(Health varchar(20), Diet varchar(20))
INSERT @t values
('Very good', 'Very good'),
('Poor', 'Good'),
('Poor', 'Poor')
```

Query 1:

```
;WITH CTE1 as
(
  SELECT Health, count(*) CountHealth
  FROM @t --[Health].[Questionaire] 
  GROUP BY health
), CTE2 as
(
  SELECT Diet, count(*) CountDiet
  FROM @t --[Health].[Questionaire] 
  GROUP BY Diet
)
SELECT 
  coalesce(Health, Diet) Grade, 
  coalesce(CountHealth, 0) CountHealth, 
  coalesce(CountDiet, 0) CountDiet
FROM CTE1
FULL JOIN
CTE2
ON CTE1.Health = CTE2.Diet
ORDER BY CountHealth DESC
```

Result 1:

```
Grade     CountHealth  CountDiet
Poor      2            1
Very good 1            1
Good      0            1
```

Mixing the results like that is really not good practice, so here is a different solution

Query 2:

```
SELECT Health, count(*) Count, 'Health' Grade
FROM @t --[Health].[Questionaire] 
GROUP BY health
UNION ALL
SELECT Diet, count(*) CountDiet, 'Diet'
FROM @t --[Health].[Questionaire] 
GROUP BY Diet
ORDER BY Grade, Count DESC
```

Result 2:

```
Health     Count Grade
Good       1     Diet
Poor       1     Diet
Very good  1     Diet
Poor       2     Health
Very good  1     Health
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the table to itself, but (as your sample data shows) to deal with gaps in actual data for specific values.

If you have a table that has the range of health/diet values:

```
select
  v.value Status,
  count(a.id) healthCount,
  count(b.id) DietCount
from health_diet_values v
left join Questionaire a on a.health = v.value
left join Questionaire b on b.diet = v.value
group by v.value
```

or if you don't have such a table, you need to generate the list of values manually and join from that:

```
select
  v.value Status,
  count(a.id) healthCount,
  count(b.id) DietCount
from (select 'Very Good' value union all
      select 'Good' union all
      select 'Poor') v
left join Questionaire a on a.health = v.value
left join Questionaire b on b.diet = v.value
group by v.value
```

Both of these queries produce zeroes if there is no matching data for the value.

Note that in your desired output you have a redundant column - you repeat the value column. The above queries produce output that looks like:

```
Status    HealthCount DietCount
-------------------------------
Very Good           2         1
Good                1         1
Poor                0         1
```

Comment: this is seriously bad. Did you try it before posting ?

Comment: @t-c no i didn't try it - SQL fiddle is down. But why do you say this is "seriously bad"?

Comment: was looking mainly at the last part, no naming of the column in the subselect in "v" and group by 1,3 ? What is that ? Ok seems to work besides that. So seriously bad is a bit harsh.

Comment: @t-c ah yes - I've added the missing column name. Thx. And "1, 3" is in the SQL standard for group by and order by clauses for listing columns by position rather than by expression (it's just easier to read)

Comment: @Grax Not unless it is a new feature after sql-server 2008. You can use order by on a column number, but not group by

Comment: 1,3 works for order by statements, but it doesn't seem to work for group by statements.   Sorry for my confusion

Comment: I don't think the theory is terrible but the query does not return correct results.  In my test, the query adds a extra count when the diet and health values are different.  Also, personally I find the column number syntax harder to read, not easier, although I can allow for personal preference.

Comment: @t-c damn sqlserver... Microsoft always has to do it the "hard way". I have edited the code to not use numbers for columns (and improved on the output too).

Comment: @grax the case where you change a grouped by expression is the gotcha for me - if you group by expressions, you have to change the expression in two places. Also, the group by clause itself is redundant - it can be derived from the query and has only 1 possible legal value thus adds no value and should be eliminated from the language